# Validate model field: if value equals a key in a hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, constants

In an initializer I have a huge **COUNTRY_CODES** hash, with format:

```
{ :us => "United States, :de => "Germany" }
```

In my model I want to validate that the entered value is:

- present
- a key of my country code hash

How do I apporach this?

I can't use:

```
validates :country, :presence => true,
                    :inclusion => { :in => COUNTRY_CODES }
```

I've tried custom validators, but I get method errors when the value is nil, e.g. when I try to use value.to_sym, causing me to validate the validator and it becomes messy.

Trying to figure out the most DRY and efficient way of doing this.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to collect COUNTRY_CODES keys(symbols) as strings and validate for the inclusion. So use:

```
validates :country, :presence => true,:inclusion => { :in => COUNTRY_CODES.keys.map(&:to_s) }
```

Comment: FYI, default for inclusion is :allow_nil => false, no need for the presence of validation.

Answer (score 4):

Try `COUNTRY_CODES.keys` if you only want to check with the keys in the hash.

Answer (score 1):

Hows this?

```
validates :country, :presence => true,
                    :inclusion => { :in => COUNTRY_CODES.keys.map{|c| c.to_s}
```